# Jquery Hidden Field in Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, row, html-table, hidden-field

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to access a hidden field (by client id) within a table row using jquery.

```
$("#tblOne").find("tr").click(function() {
            var worker = $(this).find(":input").val();
        });
```

I find that the above works for a row that has only one input, but I need some help figuring out a way to get the value by the inputs name.

Here's the example of a table row. How would I access the two fields by their id's?

```
<table id="tblOne">
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:HiddenField id="hdnfld_Id" Text='<% Eval("ID") %>'></asp:HiddenField>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:HiddenField id="hdnfld_Id2" Text='<% Eval("ID2") %>'></asp:HiddenField>
</td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: You do have runat="server" on your hidden fields don't you? Is that just a typo? (Without it, you won't be getting very far)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the way you have it setup right now, you could do this:

```
$('tr td', '#tblOne').eq(0).find(':input').val(); // find input in 1st TD
$('tr td', '#tblOne').eq(1).find(':input').val(); // find input in 2nd TD
```

Using this you don't have to worry about the input's ClientID.

Answer (score 3):

I normally use a positive lookup to match the id, this method avoids requiring the client id

(id contains foo)
$(this).find("input[id*='foo']").val();

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
    $("#tblOne").find("tr").click(function() {
        var election = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();
        var worker = $(this).find('input[name=theName]').val();
    });
```

Read through this excellent article ['How to get what you want using jQuery](http://benjaminsterling.com/jquery-select-what-you-want-part-1/)' by Benjamin Sterling.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using a master page and Asp.net changes the id name. Is there a way to use clientID?
I've tried using var worker = $(this).find('input[name=<%=hdnfld_Id.ClientID %>]').val();
and i get the following error. The name 'hdnfld_Id' does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply use this:

```
jQuery("#<%=hdnfld_Id.ClientID%>")
```

Answer (score 1):

`<asp:HiddenField id="foo">` generates an `<input type="hidden" id="foo"/>` does it not?  Why don't you just do

```
$("#foo").val()
```

?

I think you need to explain what you're trying to do a bit better.  If you find that

```
$(this).find(":input").val();
```

... only works when you have one input, maybe what you're looking for is this:

```
$(this).find(":input").each(function() {
  // Prints the value of each input.
  alert($(this).val());
}
```

But as it stands, your question is not very clear.  Try editing your question and take your time to explain exactly what you want.

Comment: Well i was looking for a way to access the values in the hidden fields for the click event on a row within the table.
Each hidden field has a unique identifier for the row.
I hope that clears it up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but I was having incredible difficulty in pulling a hidden field value from within a table cell (using tablesorter on that table of course), so I am so happy to have found this line of code:

$(this).find(":input").val();

and it works wonderfully.

I also use the ".live" function, so it works even on huge tables.

THANK YOU!!!

HLR

Answer (score 1):

I have three tabs each with a Submit button causing post backs. After the click event for the submit button, I want the current tab to persist.

Step 1.

Added an **asp:HiddenField** inside the tabs div ('tabs' div holds all the three divs that have the content for my tabs).

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="sel_tab" Value="" runat="server" />
```

Step 2.

Updated the value of **sel_tab** with the click event of each button that causes a post back.

```
protected void cmdSaveDailyMeasure_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sel_tab.Value = "0";
}
protected void cmdSaveWeeklyMeasure_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sel_tab.Value = "1";
}
protected void cmdSaveMonthlyMeasure_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sel_tab.Value = "2";
}
```

Step 3. 
In my **.js** file I have the following code

```
// Tabs
$(document).ready(function() {
    var iSelectedTab = $(this).find("input[id*='sel_tab']").val();
    if (iSelectedTab == null)
        iSelectedTab = 0;    
    $('[id$=tabs]').tabs({ selected: iSelectedTab });
});
```

This works even if you are using Master Pages (i am). Don't need the <%=foo.ClientID%> part.